# Compare a value to two other values in a single expression while referring to the first value only once

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, boolean-expression

Say you have a function, `foo()`, that returns a number.

You want to check if the return value is equal to `N` or `M`.

You could do `foo() == N || foo() == M`. But that requires calling `foo()` twice.

How would you make a single boolean C expression that does this while calling `foo()` only once?

**Edit:** As already stated in the title, I want to refer to the first value *only* once. And this must be in a single C expression, i.e., no temporary variables, which requires a separate declaration statement. Otherwise the answer is trivial.

Comment: Oh whoops, that was a pretty important detail to leave out. I'm trying to do this in C.

Comment: Do you mind adding why you have these restrictions?  Are they actual restrictions or is this just a thought experiment?  There is something to be said for simple code that works versus "clever" code that may or may not work.

Comment: I'm trying to make a piece of code as compact as possible for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a temporary to store the return value of `foo` in order to not call it twice, then you can do this in a straightforward way with a couple `==` and an `||`. But if you really want the `if` as something more "atomic" you can do this with a temporary value like this:

```
  int temp;
  if (temp = foo(), !((temp ^ N) * (temp ^ M))) {
    // your code here
  }
```

It might save a branch from the short-circuit evaluation, depending on what the compiler generates.

**Without a temporary:**
If you don't care about modifying N and M, you can do the test in a statement without a temp. `N'` holds `N ^ M`, `M'` holds `M ^ foo()`. So `N' ^ M'` gives `N ^ foo()`. The comma operator is evaluated left to right and the expression is has a value equal to its hand side.

```
  if (N ^= M, M ^= foo(), !(M * (N ^ M))) {
    // your code here
  }
```

Comment: Declaring a temp makes it no longer a single expression.

Comment: @clin18, technically if you happen to have a temp lying around this is a single expression, however I agree it violates the spirit of the question. The best way to do this really is to cache the return value of foo and then compare it to both. What is the reason it is so important to use only one expression?

Comment: @clin18, Here are a few other options: I know of a way to do this in one expression if you are allowed to modify the values you are checking against. I know of a way to add an expression to this to restore the value back to it’s original value, but it can’t be done without an extra semicolon. Or, if your goal is to have the expression syntax, you could pass the return value of foo to a function returning bool along with the two values you are checking against. I’m happy to post code on any of these if they fit your purpose and you let me know.

Comment: This is just a challenge I thought up. I was hoping there would be some kind of bit magic involving XORs that could do this. If you have interesting solutions to any variation of this problem, please do post them. I'll be happy to read them.

Comment: @clin18, I added an XOR solution that does not involve a temporary but  it modifies N and M (they have to be non-const ints). I don't think it's possible to restore their values after the check.

Answer (score 2):

```
if((x = foo()) == N || x == M) ...
```

Comment: You are implying that x is declared elsewhere, which breaks the single expression requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int x = foo();
if (x == N || x == M) ...
```

Seems rather obvious

Comment: Which is why there is the requirement of a single expression. The Declaration of x breaks that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the result of `foo()` to an intermediate variable?

```
x = foo();
if(x == N || x == M)
  ...
```

Comment: This would not be a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `N > M`, `N - M` is a power of 2, and that our unsigned integers here are 32 bits.

There should be another power of 2, `K` such that `k * (N - M)` wraps around to 0.

If `N - M` is 2<sup>i</sup>, then `K` would be 2<sup>32-i</sup>.

Then the expression `!(K * (foo() - M))` will give the answer.

But this relies on many conditions; I'm looking for a solution for all possible `N` and `M`.